# Arc length parameterization of the 2-sphere geodesics

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, spheres, geodesic

I'm trying to evaluate the arc length between two points on a 2-sphere.

The geodesic equation of a 2-sphere is:

$$\cot(\theta)=\sqrt{\frac{1-K^2}{K^2}}\cdot \sin(\phi-\phi_{0})$$

According to this article:

http://vixra.org/pdf/1404.0016v1.pdf

the arc lenght parameterization of the 2-sphere geodesics is given by:

$$\cos(\theta)=\sqrt{1-K^2}\cdot \sin(\frac{s}{R})$$

$$\tan(\phi-\phi_{0})=K \cdot \tan(\frac{s}{R})$$

However, when I evaluate the integral:

$$s=\int_{s_{1}}^{s_{2}}{ds}=s_{2}-s_{1}$$

I don't obtain the right solution.

Is there another way of parametrize the geodesics of a 2-sphere in terms of the arc length?

Comment: "between two points on a 2-sphere":  How are these two points provided?  (Cartesian coordinates?  Spherical coordinates?  Atlas/chart/local coordinate triples?  Something else?)

Comment: The two points are in spherical coordinates, the first component is $\theta$ and the second $\phi$. For example: $$P_{1}=(\frac{\pi}{4},0)$$ and $$P_{2}=(\frac{\pi}{3},\frac{\pi}{2})$$

Comment: Have you consulted Do Carmo, O'Neill, or any other intro text in differential geometry? This is a standard exercise.